# Detail of all MPI Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, mpi

Is there any document about how MPI functions such as MPI_Algather, MPI_AlltoAll, MPI_Allreduce etc.. are implemented ?

I would like to learn about their algorithm and compute the complexity of them in term of uni-directional or bi-directional bandwidth and total data transfer size for a number of nodes and fixed data size.

Comment: Use the Source, Luke^H^H^H^HiKid!

Answer (score 1):

I think the exact implementation of those algoritms varies, depending on the communication mechanism: in example a network will have tree-based reduction algorithms, while shared memory models will have different ones.

I'm not exactly sure about where to find answers to such questions, but I think that a good search for papers in [google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) or having a look at this paper list at [open-mpi.org](http://www.open-mpi.org/papers/) should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Parallel-Programming-MPI-Peter-Pacheco/dp/1558603395/ref=sr_1_10?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1314807638&sr=1-10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558603395)

shown above is great link that explains all the basic MPI algorithms and allows you to implement a simple version yourself. However, when doing comparisons between the algorithms that you have implemented and the MPI algorithms, you will see that they have made many optimizations depending on the size of the message and number of nodes that you are running on. Hopefully this helps